# JavaScript: Best way to find if a value is inside an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150) 
>   [How to check if value exists in this JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740241)

**For example:**

```
var arr = [
     {id: 1, color: 'blue'},
     {id: 2, color: 'red'},
     {id: 3, color: 'yellow'}
];

alert( indexOf('blue') ); // How can I get the index of blue??
```

Comment: Possible Duplicates:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740241/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-this-javascript-array, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Is it JSON and would you want to get ID?

Comment: @sll: Does not look like JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
found_flag = false;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].color == 'blue') {
        found_flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found_flag === true)
{
    alert(i);
} else {
    alert('not found');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply loop through the array and check the colour value:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length -1 ; i++){
    if(arr[i].color == 'red'){
        alert(i); 
    }  
}
```

And of course you could just wrap it in a helper function as follows:

```
function colourIndex(colour){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length -1 ; i++){
        if(arr[i].color == colour){
         return i; 
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate over the array, searching for the blue object. If you got it you have your index.

```
var index = 0;
for(; index<arr.length; index++) {
    if(arr[index].color == 'blue') {
        break;
    }
}
alert(index)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create a more general solution instead of duplicating code all over the place

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = (function() {
    var old = Array.prototype.indexOf ||
        function(v) {
            var i, l = this.length;
            for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
                if (this[i] === v) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };

        return function(v) {
            var i, l;
            if (typeof v != "function") {
                return old.call( this, v );
            }

            l = this.length;

            for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
                if (v.call( this, this[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
})();

arr.indexOf( function(v){return v.color == "blue";} ); //0

arr.indexOf( function(v){return v.images[0].imageData == "xxx"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Very bad method:

```
var ind = -1
$(arr).each(function(index, val){if (val.color=='blue'){ind=index;return false;}});
```

A better way could be to create another map of value which are searchable and their indexes, or something like that.